# Script to resolve mathematical expressions step by step

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to create a script similar to http://www.minimath.net/index.htm

There is a library PHP or JavaScript that solves a mathematical expression showing all the steps?

Comment: Asking for off-site recommendations is explicitly off-topic for this website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your link, check source.

1. Near line 16 you can find `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=AM_HTMLorMML-full"></script>`, this script is used to display mathematic formula.

   > [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) is a JavaScript library that allows page authors to include mathematics within their web pages.
2. Near line 90 you can find `<FORM action="cgi-bin/minimath_cgi.exe"  method="GET" onsubmit="submitCalculationF();">`.

   The `submitCalculationF()` function (near line 12 in source) calls `submitCalculation("F")` function (in http://www.minimath.net/main.js)

   If you type a simple request like `1+1`, the values pass by `submitCalculation` function and the script to resolve is get by a call like this http://www.minimath.net/cgi-bin/minimath_cgi.exe?LANG=E&INPUTERROR=0&MTHINPUT=1%2B1. The script to resolve is here.

Comment: I had seen mathjax but it is not just a way to display the functions?

Comment: Yes. You are right. I edit my answer.

Comment: but I have no access to CGI, it could use a PHP library that solves the expression

Comment: maybe... mail to info@minimath.net to get `minimath_cgi.exe`